# I am facing issues after updated flutter to 3.13.4 to 3.7.7 the issue is BuildForInputLogger

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error: The non-abstract class 'BuildForInputLogger' is missing implementations for these members:

- Logger.onLevelChanged

Answer (score 0):

1. flutter upgrade
2. dart pub upgrade
3. dart pub outdated
4. dart pub upgrade --major-versions
   then run the

flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

If you are using the DIO then update the dio class according to the new update

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with `build_runner` package in the latest build. For now consider using `build_runner 2.3.3` for your project in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```yaml
# build runner
build_runner: 2.3.3
```

After which run the below commands:

```bash
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Your project should now run properly.